# Android - Expand ellipsized TextView

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to implement a function that when a `TextView` contains too many lines of text, it can be collapsed into 2 lines after a user taps a button. It is expected that when the user taps that button again, the `TextView` should then show the full text it contains. 
In the `collapseView()` method, I use `setEllipsize` as below:

```
private void collapseView() {
        m_vwText.setMaxLines(2);
        m_vwText.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
        m_vwExpandButton.setText(EXPAND);
    }
```

So I wonder what should I do in my `expandView()` method to show all lines contained in the `TextView`. Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea would be to take the original TextView value into a temporary variable and keep it there, and make use of it in the `customView()` method.

ex:, in `onCreate()`

```
String originalText=m_vwText.getText().toString().
```

Then in your `expandView()` you just work with `originalText`

```
private void expandView(){
   m_vwText.setText(originalText);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried that but somehow it doesn't work (the `TextView` still shows the ellipsized text.) I'll try to find where the problem really is.

Comment: Most probably the problem is because the TextView keeps the ellipsize settings from the collapseView(): m_vwText.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);. In the expandView() you will need somehow to reset this setting and then set the original text. Please mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question.

Comment: It's weird that when I created a `Toast` to try showing the original text and it shows the full text just fine, but the call `setText` I made for `m_vwText` still fails to show the full text. This is really confusing to me.

Comment: Could you paste here the code that displays the Toast, and how you made for m_vwText? Tip: before displaying the original text in your TextView, try to clear the ellipsize with: setEllipsize(null).

Comment: Okay I found the problem: it's because I use `setMaxLines(2)` so the maximum number of lines in the TextView is always 2. I changed it to a really large number and it works perfectly.